# How does a view know he was sent back in front?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My problem is that i don't know how to reload some data when view gets back in front. So my situation is like this. I have view one from which i load view 2 and then in view 2 i update some data used in view 1. But when i press back view one doesn't update. So i need to know which function should i implement for when view came back on. I'm looking for somthing like:

```
    - (void)viewDidRELoad
    {//do my updating of stuff..
```

It would be also fine if i can call some function from second view ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are probably looking for `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: That/s exactly what i was looking for, i will except ur answer in 10 min. Tenx!